# Extract one array item from a JSON according to the URL using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I hope my title wasn't too confusing.  Basically what I have is a list of portfolio items whose data is gathered from a JSON file.  Each portfolio item has a url that will navigate to the single portfolio item.

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```
[
{
     "url": "nutcracker",
    "name": "Nutcracker Main Street Ballet",
     "snippet": "Trifold Playbill",
     "imgurl": "img/nutcracker.jpg",
     "keyword": "trifold brochure folder over foldover folded"},

MORE
]
```

And here is the controller that is gathering the data:

```
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('items/items.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.pages = data; 
  });

});
```

And here, the routing:

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/list', {templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', controller: 'ListCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/:pageUrl', {templateUrl: 'partials/single-item.html', controller: 'ItemCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/list'});
}]);
```

Now each portfolio item uses the 'url' datum to dictate the url.  So this item would provide a url of: www.mysite.com/#/nutcracker.

**What I want to do is search the URL for 'nutcracker' and then find that corresponding item in the JSON array and use it's data to populate the single portfolio page.**

I hope this isn't too confusing.  Please ask questions if you think you can help but may not be sure as to what I'm looking for!

Thank you very much!

Comment: there are a few different techniques that could be used to approach this need.  Have you tried anything yet and run into a problem, or are you just asking for the best approach?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm a beginner at Angular and honestly don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$location.path()` to access the path, strip off the leading "/", then use the path to search the array (example uses `$.grep()` to do this because question was tagged jQuery)...

```
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
  $http.get('items/items.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.pages = data; 

    var path = $location.path();  // "/nutcracker"
    if (path.length) {
      path = path.substring(1); // "nutcracker"
    }
    // find matching page in pages
    $scope.page = $.grep(pages, function (page) { return page.url === path; })[0];
  });

});
```

Comment: i'm thinking if you take this approach, `$location` will cause the app to re-route, which will cause a redirect loop. +1 for use of `$grep`

Comment: Does calling `$location.path()` trigger a route change? I thought it just returns the current route. At least that's what the docs seem to suggest? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Ok Anthony, let me try this method in the morning... It is getting late here.  I will update you if this helps me.  From looking at it, it looks like it might be in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, you're right. My bad.  you need to return with it or pass it params in order to trigger a route change.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond.  This didn't seem to work for what I was doing.  When the url changes `example.com/#/nutcracker` it doesn't extract just the object with the corresponding url and so it doesn't extract any data.